# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '28,29,30,31,32' to data type smallint

Tags: sql, string, variables, sql-server-2016

Trying to do some custom dumps to csv files for a customer's access control system, having trouble assigning a string to a variable.

Each Badge Reader would be something along the lines of machine 1-20 and reader 1-20 so essentially I could do all of this with or statements but I would need 1 for each reader.

I think I know the issues, and its having trouble discerning the different numbers with the comma and trying to convert. 
It works perfectly when I change it to single variables.

```
Declare @Panels as varchar;
Declare @Readers as varchar;

Set @Panels = ('28,39,30,31,32')
Set @Readers = ('1,2,3,4,5,6')

SELECT READER.READERDESC, EVENTS.CARDNUM, EVENT.EVDESCR, EVENTS.EVENT_TIME_UTC
FROM EMP
INNER JOIN EVENTS ON EMP.ID = EVENTS.EMPID 
INNER JOIN EVENT
   ON EVENTS.EVENTTYPE = EVENT.EVTYPEID 
   AND EVENTS.EVENTID = EVENT.EVID 
INNER JOIN READER
   ON EVENTS.MACHINE = READER.PANELID 
   AND EVENTS.DEVID = READER.READERID
WHERE EVENT_TIME_UTC >= DATEADD (DAY, -1, (CONVERT (date, GETDATE())))
   AND EVENT_TIME_UTC <= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
   AND (MACHINE = @Panels AND DEVID = @Readers)
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3,4,5,6' to data type int.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added that for more information, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The error is because `('28,39,30,31,32')` is not an int -- it is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

First, in SQL Server, your code will not generate this error.

This code:

```
Declare @Panels as varchar;
Declare @Readers as varchar;

Set @Panels = ('28,39,30,31,32')
Set @Readers = ('1,2,3,4,5,6')
```

assigns the values `'2'` and `'1'` to the variables respectively.  Why?  Because you need the *length* when declaring a string.

Second, strings are strings and they are compared in their entirety.  This code:

```
MACHINE = @Panels
```

says "I'm comparing an integer to a string.  They are not same type, so I'd better convert.  Let me check.  Oh, the rules say to convert the string to an integer.  Oops, can't do that.  ERROR!".

You seem to want to *split* the string.  You would do that as:

```
MACHINE IN (SELECT * FROM SPLIT(@Panels, ',') s)
```

This still has the implicit type conversion, but it would normally work.  In production code, I would be more pedantic:

```
MACHINE IN (SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT, VALUE) FROM SPLIT(@Panels, ',') s)
```

Comment: In production code, I would try to avoid working with delimited strings altogether...